# I can't run my old Android Studio Project in new Android Studio Flamingo

Tags: android, android-studio

I had an old project created with java. Today I had to upgrade my Android Studio to Android Studio Flamingo. I opened my old project with Flamingo but "run" option is greyed out.

[image]

There is no Sync option in File

[image]

I tried to change something in build.gradle, settings.gradle and there is no "sync" option appearing on top.

My Gradle settings look like this:
[image]

My project settings look like this:
[image]

Can anybody help me how can I run my project?

P.S. I have a genymotion device open. I can run new flutter projects with that without any problem. But I can't run my old android studio (Java) project.

2nd Edit:

I can see devices in new created projects. But in my old project nothing happens. The picture above shows new created project and under that there is my old project.

[image]

3rd Edit:
There is no gradle tab in View -> Tool Windows

[image]

Comment: Is there any error showing up on the BUILD tab that you could share?

Comment: Nope because I can't do anything. I cannot update gradle, I cannot run project or build proejct. Lastly, I updated my app 2 years ago with older version of Android Studio. Now I updated Android Studio to Flamingo version and tried to open my old app. But nothing happens.

Comment: I assume you tried reloading you project by closing and re-opening the project. Maybe you could try to open GRADLE tab and right click on your project and click `Reload Gradle Project`.

Comment: Yes I tried those things. I cannot Reload Gradle Project there is no such option. Maybe I create a new project and copy codes from my old project. That would work right?

Comment: If you cannot invoke a Gradle sync it's pretty nasty, but I'm fairly sure it can be resolved. I'm curious though, doesn't `View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle` show the Gradle tab for you?

Comment: I do not know if you have similar situation as I had some time ago. I work on MacOS and I used to have my Android projects on external drive. It worked fine until one of the latest uplifts of Android Studio. I had to copy my projects to the main drive and from there everything worked fine. From external drive they behave similar as yours.

Comment: @basileus files are in my main drive.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have no emulated device created to run your project upon. You need either to create an emulated device through the device manager (in Tools options), or connect a device with adb.

[image]

Comment: I didn't mention that but I have a genymotion device. I created a new flutter project with android studio and I can run this project in genymotion but I can't run my old android studio(java) project.

Comment: I see. But this device seems to be not connected to Android Studio anyway. Otherwise you'd see it next to "Run the application" button. Perhaps you need to connect it with adb commands?

Comment: I edited my post above to show you what you are missing (compare with your first picture). When you connect the external device, like with adb commands in Terminal window (adb pair, adb connect  etc.), you'll see the device in the same way. Without any device connected it is natural, that you cannot run your project in Android Studio - nowhere to run upon. However you should still be able to generate i.e. APK file.

Comment: I updated my post again. There are connected devices. But in my old project I don't see them. I can't do anything I can't upgrade gradle. I can't build, I can't run.